# Querying oracle in Hebrew in Python 2.7

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I try to query Oracle (with cx_oracle) and my query is supposed to return Hebrew values.
However, when I print it I see a diamond with question mark.

I tried to use UTF-8 and cp1252 and all of this.
Either I don't use it correctly or there is another solution, I couldn't solve it.

Is some one know?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I can copy it here. But it is a simple query using cx_oracle, execute and fetch all..

Comment: I am interested in how do you open a connection - how did you `tried to use UTF-8 and cp1252` ? And in addtition - what is a result of `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS` (this query will get NLS settinsg of your database) ?

Comment: To check the DB character set run `SELECT value AS db_charset FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'`
To check what you have set in Python (the "client" of the DB) run `SELECT DISTINCT client_charset AS client_charset FROM v$session_connect_info WHERE sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')`  The answer to @krokodilko's question is important.

Comment: Ok, sI my connection sentence is just: conn=cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dbname). Tried to add utf8 and all of that and it didn't work. Just to emphasize that it works well in SQL navigator. The result of @krokodiko query is Hebrew in the NLS_LANGUAGE. In Christoper query I see that the result is 'IW8ISO8859P8'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using UTF-8 in your connection by using the following code when creating a connection:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@host/service", encoding="UTF-8",
        nencoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: I made cx_oracle.connect('username', 'password', 'db's, encoding='utf-8') and it didn't work. Think you have spelling issues in the nenecoding

Comment: Yes, there was a spelling issue in the code. I have just corrected it. Are you querying from an NVARCHAR2 or NCHAR or NCLOB column? If so, that would address the issue for you.